# Strange behavior of breakable boxes for tcolorbox package

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, polyglossia, arabic

While using Latex to produce an Arabic document as usual, I encountered a problem related to spacing of boxes used by `tcolorbox` package.

The following codes is an example for what I mean

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[breakable,external,fitting,hooks,magazine,poster,raster,skins,
theorems,vignette,xparse,listings,]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\section{عنوان باللغة العربية}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,
title={صندوق 1
       \LR{Breakable}%
      }
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,
title={صندوق 2
       \LR{Breakable}%
       }
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
سطر جديد
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable,
title={صندوق 3
\LR{Breakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, %Note that breakable option is discarded
title={صندوق 3
\LR{unbreakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق غير قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{عنوان آخر}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, %Note that breakable option is discarded
title={صندوق 5
\LR{Unbreakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق عادي لا ينقسم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The result is extra space before every breakable box while spacing for unbreakable boxes go natural as I think as shown in image below.

[image]

I tried using usual solutions like using command `\vspace{<dim>}` or `\vspace*{<dim>}`, but it fails when placing boxes directly after sections.

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional box, probably from one of the bidi patches. As a work-around you could define you a key that reverts the space:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[breakable,external,fitting,hooks,magazine,poster,raster,skins,
theorems,vignette,xparse,listings,]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\tcbset{bidibreakable/.style={breakable,enlarge top initially by=-1\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\section{عنوان باللغة العربية}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, bidibreakable,
title={صندوق 1
       \LR{Breakable}%
      }
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, bidibreakable,
title={صندوق 2
       \LR{Breakable}%
       }
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
سطر جديد
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, bidibreakable,
title={صندوق 3
\LR{Breakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, %Note that breakable option is discarded
title={صندوق 3
\LR{unbreakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق غير قابل للتقسيم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{عنوان آخر}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, %Note that breakable option is discarded
title={صندوق 5
\LR{Unbreakable}%
}
]
هذا صندوق عادي لا ينقسم على عدة صفحات
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]