# Cartouche textbox

Tags: boxes, hieroglf

How can I draw the "Cartouche" textbox shape provided in the "hieroglf" package through the use of the "Tikz package" or any other means (If there is a more simple way than using the Tikz package, this would be better) so that I am able to also put text inside the Cartouche, since I cannot use the "hieroglf" package for certain reasons.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}  

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}
\babelfont{hieroglyphs}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{boldline} 



\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [
        black,
        ultra thick,
        draw, 
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=3ex,
        inner sep=0.25em,
        ]
        {{\textbf{\Huge\texthieroglyphs{}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption
[خرطوشة منقوش عليها اسم الملكة كليوباترا بالهيروغليفية]
{
خرطوشة منقوش عليها اسم الملكة كليوباترا بالهيروغليفية
\cite{bbb}
}
\label{fig:F-1_2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't compile your example, it complains about `\texthieroglyphs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\newtcbox{\CartoucheBox}{colback=white,boxrule=0.6pt}

\begin{document} 
\CartoucheBox{A cartouche box.} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a couple of coordinate computations (using the `calc` library) you can get this shape:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/cartouche/.is family,/cartouche/.cd,frame sep/.initial=1mm,
end width/.initial=2mm,frame arc/.initial=3pt}
\newtcbox{\CartoucheBox}{colback=white,boxrule=0pt,enhanced,colframe=white,
overlay={\draw[thin] let \p1=($(frame.north east)-(frame.south west)$),
\n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/frame sep}},
\n2={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/end width}},
\n3={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/frame arc}},
\n4={asin((\n2/2+\n3)/(\y1/2+\n1))} in 
(frame.south west) arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,radius=\y1/2] 
-- (frame.north east) arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=\y1/2] 
-- cycle
([yshift=-\n1]frame.south west)
 arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,radius={\y1/2+\n1}]
 -- ([yshift=\n1]frame.north east)
arc[start angle=90,end angle=\n4,radius={\y1/2+\n1}]
arc[start angle=180+\n4,end angle=360,radius=\n3] coordinate(aux)
-- ([yshift=\n1-\n3]frame.north-|aux) 
arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=\n3]
-- ($([yshift=-\n1+\n3]frame.south-|aux)+(2*\n3,0)$)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=-180,radius=\n3] 
let \p2=($(aux)-(frame.east)$) in
-- ([yshift=-2*\y2]aux)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=180-\n4,radius=\n3]
arc[start angle=-\n4,end angle=-90,radius={\y1/2+\n1}] -- cycle;
}}

\begin{document} 
\CartoucheBox{A cartouche box.} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As for the code of your MWE, this has nothing particular to do with this `tcolorbox` but with the fact that you use `arabic` as the main language, and thus write from right to left. I have do not know how to solve this in general, and it might make sense to look at questions and answer of [threads like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506280/194703). This is a discussion on which I have no expertise. All I can say is that if you locally switch to a left-to-right language such as English, there is no problem. For some reason, Ti*k*Z seems to take care of this automatically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/cartouche/.is family,/cartouche/.cd,frame sep/.initial=1mm,
end width/.initial=2mm,frame arc/.initial=3pt}
\newtcbox{\CartoucheBox}[1][]{colback=white,boxrule=0pt,enhanced,colframe=white,
overlay={\draw[thin] let \p1=($(frame.north east)-(frame.south west)$),
\n1={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/frame sep}},
\n2={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/end width}},
\n3={\pgfkeysvalueof{/cartouche/frame arc}},
\n4={asin((\n2/2+\n3)/(\y1/2+\n1))} in 
(frame.south west) arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,radius=\y1/2] 
-- (frame.north east) arc[start angle=90,end angle=-90,radius=\y1/2] 
-- cycle
([yshift=-\n1]frame.south west)
 arc[start angle=270,end angle=90,radius={\y1/2+\n1}]
 -- ([yshift=\n1]frame.north east)
arc[start angle=90,end angle=\n4,radius={\y1/2+\n1}]
arc[start angle=180+\n4,end angle=360,radius=\n3] coordinate(aux)
-- ([yshift=\n1-\n3]frame.north-|aux) 
arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=\n3]
-- ($([yshift=-\n1+\n3]frame.south-|aux)+(2*\n3,0)$)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=-180,radius=\n3] 
let \p2=($(aux)-(frame.east)$) in
-- ([yshift=-2*\y2]aux)
arc[start angle=0,end angle=180-\n4,radius=\n3]
arc[start angle=-\n4,end angle=-90,radius={\y1/2+\n1}] -- cycle;
}}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{amiri}

\babelfont{hieroglyphs}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}


\begin{document}
\CartoucheBox{ABC}

\CartoucheBox[fontupper=\Huge\bfseries]{\texthieroglyphs{}}


\selectlanguage{english}
\CartoucheBox{ABC}

\CartoucheBox[fontupper=\Huge\bfseries]{\texthieroglyphs{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but can it be modified to have a vertical line at the RHS end, similar to this image (but the one in this image is vertical, the horizontal one you made is ok, no need for the vertical one) http://www.historyshistories.com/uploads/5/5/3/8/55383793/103890374.jpeg

Comment: @Silva You say "have a vertical line at the RHS end" and "no need for the vertical one". Do you have clearer description and/or image?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean that the cartcouche remain horizontal, with a vertical line at the RHS, since the link I sent had a cartcouche but placed in a vertical form.

Comment: @Silva Sure, I added one of these.

Comment: Upon using \texthieroglyphs{} inside the command, the letters are out of the box ad the box is shifted to the RHS. This command \CartoucheBox{{\textbf{\Huge\texthieroglyphs{}}}}, is not workng properly

Comment: @Silva First of all, I think the correct usage for large fonts is to use `fontupper=\Huge\bfseries`. Second, unfortunately there is no complete code from your side that allows me to so test your suggestion. I'd have to guess what you are really using. Please add a minimal working example that demonstrates an actual use case.

Comment: I added an MWE, so that you may experiment on it

Comment: Fixed it, forgot to add \babelfont{hieroglyphs}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}

Comment: @Silva The problem comes from the arabic conventions to write from left to right, not from the hieroglyphs. So if you locally switch to English, say, it works. I added a version that does that but I would assume that there are some general tcolorbox solutions for this, which I happen not to know.